# suggestions for using protocol to stream images

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, ffserver

The target is that a user sends a stream of images to a server. The server should forward those to a media server for showing as a live continuous video to clients.

following are the thought for implementing, kindly tell if they are ok.

Use a lightweight rtmp server to accept stream of images from a user (please suggest if this is even possible via rtmp and if it cab be easiy and efficiently done otherwise)

use ffmpeg to use the rtmp (or other) url as input and send those images to ffserver for streaming. (am also confused here, if ffserver is fed with images continuosly, can it show those images as video as long as the images are coming)

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier solution would be to use an RTMP live ecoder that is capable of streaming a slideshow. This can be achieved by playing the slideshow using Windows Photo Viewer and then setting the live encoder to capture the Windows Photo Viewer output and stream it as live. Two RTMP encoders that should be able to do this are OBS (Open broadcaster software) and XSplit. Another (free) solution would be to use Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder in combination with a software called ManyCam. ManyCam can capture feed from video, images, etc and feed it to FMLE using a driver. Install ManyCam and create a slideshow of images in the playlist option. Then start FMLE and select the ManyCam driver. You can now stream the slideshow as live to an rtmp server.